# The text within a div element is ignoring the CSS3 animation controls. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple menu that I am trying to get working - however, while I have the basic animation going, the child content inside the animated div is NOT hidden. This is pure CSS3, and I am trying to avoid jQuery IF it can be done at all. It uses the checkbox hack to act as a fake button to trigger the menu.

[image]

In this state, the menu is hidden but the content text is still clearly showing.
The text should be hidden along with the div that it's contained in.

HTML:

```
<body>
<input type="checkbox" value="selected" id="exCheckBoxID" class="exTooltip-input">
<label for="exCheckBoxID" class="exTooltip-Label exTooltipTopLeft"></label> 


<div id="exMC" class="exMC-TopLeftPosition">
    Test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.exTooltip-Label {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.exTooltip-input {
    display: none;
}

.exTooltip-input:not(checked) ~ #exMC {
    height: 0px;
}

.exTooltip-input:checked ~ #exMC {   
    height: 97%;
}

#exMC {
    position: fixed;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #565656;  
    -webkit-transition : all 0.30s ease-out;
    -moz-transition : all 0.30s ease-out;
    -o-transition : all 0.30s ease-out;
     transition : all 0.30s ease-out;   
}
```

The menu is written inside a standard HTML5 template, with 
for consistency, but it seems like the Chrome stylesheet may be overriding things anyway. However, this same issue shows up in Firefox and Opera as well.

What is it that I am missing, in order to hide the contents of the menu when the
animation is in it's "closed" state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `height` you could use the `display: block` & `display: none` properties but that would remove the animation.

However you can use the `visibility` property to achieve what you want here.

Refer to attached code:

```css
.exTooltip-Label {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.exTooltip-input {
  display: none;
}

.exTooltip-input ~ #exMC {
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  /* display: none; */
}

.exTooltip-input:checked ~ #exMC {
  height: 97%;
  visibility: visible;
  /* display: block; */
}

#exMC {
  position: fixed;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #565656;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.30s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="selected" id="exCheckBoxID" class="exTooltip-input">
<label for="exCheckBoxID" class="exTooltip-Label exTooltipTopLeft"></label>


<div id="exMC" class="exMC-TopLeftPosition">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: -That- seems to have done it! I've been trying any number of combinations of display: and others. Didn't think to try that particular control.